# I have 3 for loops. I'm only getting the most recent loop, all earlier data gets over written. any idea?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
counter = 0

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)


for airport in airportList: 

  table0data = [[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].find_all('td')] for i in range(len(data_rows))]

  table0datahold = []

  for i in range(len(data_rows)):
    table0_data = [counter]

    for td in data_rows[i].find_all('td'):

      table0_data.append(td.getText(strip=True))



    table0datahold.append(table0_data)

  table0data = table0datahold

  df = pd.DataFrame(table0data, columns= [])
```

there loops need help with the code, it rewrites old data. looking for a way for it to not throw an error

Comment: Hi, can you make sure you fix your indentation (for example `for i in range(len(data_rows))]` is randomly indented, and is also missing `:`, as well as remove comments such as: `...scraping data off of HTML...`. Both of these are important, and Python uses indentation for flow-control, and comments only work when prefixed with `#`.

Comment: `table0datahold = []` wipes it out

Comment: @Darkstarone that is part of the earlier line. updated to make it visibly more pleasing

Answer (score 2):

```
table0data = [[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].find_all('td')]
    for i in range(len(data_rows))]

table0datahold = []

for i in range(len(data_rows)):
    ...
    table0datahold.append(table0_data)
table0data = table0datahold
```

You do something with `table0data` than you override it in every loop, this maybe your problem? Your indentation may be inproper, or you've just typed it wrong.